# Browse Carousel Card not working for google assistant in Dialogflow

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying out **browse carousel card** (in rich responses) feature available for Google Assistant in Google's Dialogflow.

I am getting only simple response as shown:.

[image: Dialogflow Console]

Pasted below the Raw API response (no instances of browse carouse card response).

```
    {
  "responseId": "ea913388-8753-458c-b033-396512d1af42-e13762d2",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "show browse carousel",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
        "simpleResponses": {
          "simpleResponses": [
            {
              "textToSpeech": "sample text"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE"
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/leafy-winter-268704/agent/intents/bd457567-02c8-4e15-aca7-c32adfcb45f2",
      "displayName": "sampleintent"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```

This is the simulator response. The bot is getting disconnected when an intent with browse carousel is triggered.

[image: google assistant simulator response]

Am I doing it in the correct way? what can be done to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a Browse Carousel, but attempting to test it with a Smart Display. Smart Displays don't support links, so they can't support the Browse Carousel.

You can switch to testing it with Android and you should be able to see the Browse Carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked. I have another query: I am trying to create a browse carousel card response from webhook but didn't work. Can u guide me by listing some quick checkups as before?

Comment: Glad the answer has helped. It sounds like your query is a new question - go ahead and create a new StackOverflow question for it, showing your webhook code as well as any other debugging that you may have.